# Ошибка при попытке подключиться к Oracle DB (Failed to connect to server or failed to parse connect string)

Tags: c#, база-данных, oracle

Добрый день

при попытке через c# код подключиться к оракловой базе, 
получил такую вот ошибку
скачал отсюда [Oracle Data Access Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html) 
поставил пакет через нагет managementdataaccess
Далее в самой программе добавил ссылки на Oracle.DataAccess

и при попытке подключиться получил ошибку 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где сама строка подключения?

Comment: dvd =
   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = какойтоайпи)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL) 
    )
  )

Comment: посмотрите примеры тут https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: попробуйте такой вариант заменить `dvd` на `Data Source`, по ссылке выше как раз есть такой вариант с отсылкой на проблемы в VS